# Как в админке изменить язык админки в плагине WPML?

Tags: wordpress

Стоит плагин WPML, но ВСЁ на немецком языке... сделал изменения языка на английский во всевозможных настройках...все на немецком осталось...
КАК мне админку сделать на английском языке?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не там переключаете. То, что вы показали, относится к языкам вывода на сайте.

Язык консоли (админки) сайта устанавливается в профиле пользователя:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: слава Богу я знаю ГДЕ меняется язык самой админки!и таки он меняется при одном "НО". Если отключить плагин wpml...В данный момент там стоит english(как я и написал в вопросе)

Comment: Ничего подобного. Я вам показал скрин со своего сайта kagg.eu, где я переключил с русского на английский без проблем.

Comment: я добавил скрин из настроек админки, если Вы не верите

Comment: Почему не верю? Конечно, верю. Только обратите внимание на то, что я вам дал картинку с настройками **пользователя**. А вы мне показываете картинку настройки языка всего сайта.

Comment: да, там как раз у меня и НЕ те настройки что нужно. СПАСИБО!)